# What is the relation between back-propagation and reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, backpropagation

What is the relation between back-propagation and reinforcement learning?

Answer (score 6):

Backpropagation is a subroutine often used when training Artificial Neural Networks with a Gradient Descent learning algorithm. Gradient Descent requires the computation of the error gradient, i.e. derivatives, of a cost function with respect to the network parameters. BP allows you to find this gradient a lot faster than using naive methods.

Reinforcement Learning refers to inferring "optimal" behavior, i.e. a strategy, of an agent maximizing some goal in an environment. Depending on the specific RL algorithm, BP may be employed to adjust the parameters of a function approximator used to represent aspects of the environment and or the agent.